# regex extracting n-digit numbers from string

Tags: regex, vba

here is my code:

```
Dim sPartIDNumberArray() As String
Dim strIn as String

...

Dim objRegex
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
 .Global = True
 .Pattern = "(\d{7})+"
sPartIDNumberArray = .Execute(strIn)
End With

FirstPartID = sPartIDNumberArray(1)
SecondPartID = sPartIDNumberArray(2)
```

I need to extract two 7-digit numbers from text string like

> Punktschweissen\3-Blech\1384156 RE und 1375188
>   ZB RE 20 PART 1

should not the .Execute method work here?
I need FirstPartID = 1384156 and SecondPartID = 1375188
Thank you  in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign the result of `.Execute` method to an array of strings. It returns an object of `IMatchCollection2` type.

Here is the code that should work:

```
Sub reg()
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim regexMatches As Object
    Dim strIn As String
    Dim FirstPartID As String
    Dim SecondPartID As String


    strIn = "Punktschweissen\3-Blech\1384156 RE und 1375188 ZB RE 20 PART 1"


    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d{7})+"
        Set regexMatches = .Execute(strIn)
    End With

    FirstPartID = regexMatches(0)  'sPartIDNumberArray(1)
    SecondPartID = regexMatches(1) 'sPartIDNumberArray(2)

End Sub
```